# create button that refresh a captcha

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i created a captcha based on a tutorial. the tutorial uses a session variable in the main page and a separate php file(for creating the captcha image) to create the captcha. the tutorial uses rand() to create the code them trim it using substr(). this is the [link](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/create_captcha_protection.php) of the tutorial.

to check the captcha,the tutorial uses request which i don't really understand since i am new to coding in php, javascript and jquery. so, what i did is i've created a function that appends elements of an array then put it in a session variable. then in the separate php file, i removed the rand() and the substr() and used the session variable as the code. i am also saving the value of the code from my array in the `data-attr-captcha` of the image which is used for validation.

now, i want to create a "refresh captcha button" but i couldn't figure out what to do. do i need to do it on php or on javascript? i want to do it on my own and not relying on reCaptcha.

its so frustrating that i can't add anything in the separate php file

here my relevant php code:

```
$_SESSION["security_code"] = createCaptchaImg();

function createCaptchaImg(){
    $strArr = array("1","2","3","4","5","6",
                    "7","8","9","0","a","b",
                    "c","d","e","f","g","h",
                    "i","j","k","l","m","n",
                    "o","p","q","r","s","t",
                    "u","v","w","x","y","z");
    $captchaLen = 5;
    for($x = 0; $x < $captchaLen; $x++){
        $y = $strArr[rand(0, sizeOf($strArr))];
        $captchaTxt .= $y;

    }

    return $captchaTxt;
}
```

the separate php file:

```
<?php
//Start the session so we can store what the security code actually is
session_start();
//Send a generated image to the browser 
create_image(); 
exit(); 

function create_image(){

    $security_code = $_SESSION["security_code"];

    //Set the image width and height 
    $width = 100; 
    $height = 20;  

    //Create the image resource 
    $image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  

    //We are making three colors, white, black and gray 
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
    $black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0); 
    $grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); 

    //Make the background black 
    ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $black); 

    //Add randomly generated string in white to the image
    ImageString($image, 60 , 30, 3, $security_code, $white); 

    //Throw in some lines to make it a little bit harder for any bots to break 
    //ImageRectangle($image, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1,$grey); 
    imageline($image, 0, $height/2, $width, $height/2, $grey);
    imageline($image, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height, $grey);

    //Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

    //Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
    ImageJpeg($image);

    //Free up resources
    ImageDestroy($image);
}
function createCaptchaImg(){
    $strArr = array("1","2","3","4","5","6",
                    "7","8","9","0","a","b",
                    "c","d","e","f","g","h",
                    "i","j","k","l","m","n",
                    "o","p","q","r","s","t",
                    "u","v","w","x","y","z");
    $captchaLen = 5;
    for($x = 0; $x < $captchaLen; $x++){
        $y = $strArr[rand(0, sizeOf($strArr))];
        $captchaTxt .= $y;

    }

    return $captchaTxt;
}

?>
```

the image and the refresh button:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="regCaptchaImg" class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 fsForm text-right"  id="regContCaptchaVal">Captcha Image</label>
        <div id="regContCaptchaImg" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 fcBlack">
            <img class="ll-error-form"  data-attr-captcha="<?php echo $_SESSION["security_code"];?>" id="regCaptchaImg2" name="regCaptchaImg2" src="cms/createCaptchaImg.php">
            <input type="button" src="cms/refresh.png" id="captchaRefresh" style="" onclick="" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 bRxSi">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="regCaptchaCode" class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 fsForm text-right"  id="regLblCaptcha">Captcha Code</label>
        <div id="regContCaptchaCode" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 fcBlack"> 
            <input name="regCaptchaCode" id="regCaptchaCode" type="text" class="form-control-c ll-error-form bRxSi" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a JavaScript (and in your case, jQuery) function that does two things:

1. Replaces the current image with a new image.
2. Replaces the `data-attr-captcha` attribute.

To accomplish this, the refresh button should make a request that clears your current `$_SESSION['security_code']`. If this request is successful, then the jQuery should trigger a HTTP request to replace the image.

I don't have your full codebase, but I'll give you a general example.

```
$(".captchaRefresh").on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax("cms/new-captcha.php").done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#regCaptchaImg2")
            // Replace old captcha code.
            .attr('data-attr-captcha', data)
            // Reload captcha image.
            .attr('src', "cms/createCaptchaImg.php?code=" + data);
    });
});
```

Your `cms/new-captcha.php` file should do something like this.

```
$_SESSION["security_code"] = createCaptchaImg();
echo $_SESSION["security_code"];
```

The `.on('click')` calls to `cms/new-captcha.php` which creates a new captcha code and stores it to the session. It echos the new code, which is received by the JavaScript as `data`, and then set to the attribute. jQuery will then also reload the captcha image. The `?code=` request parameter is extraneous, I'm only adding that so that the browser sees the URL has changed. There are other ways of accomplishing that, but I see that as the simplest method.

Happy coding.

Comment: $ is the representation of the jQuery object. Usually, jQuery is referenced through $. If your framework does not use $ for jQuery, try replacing all `$.` instances with `jQuery.`. If that does not work, your framework is doing something weird with jQuery and you'll need to figure that out yourself.